# $scope.removeNinja is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

i'm new to angular and in one of my practice projects, i came across this issue. basically its a Directory of ninjas with some functionalities implemented using angular.

My Html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="ninjaApp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="app\lib\angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app\app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<div>
<header ng-include="'Header.html'"></header>
<div style="height: 40px;">
    <button class="btn1" ng-click="order = 'name'">Order by Name</button>
    <button class="btn2" ng-click="order = 'belt'">Order by Belt</button>
    <button class="btn3" ng-click="order = 'rate'">Order by Price</button>
    </div>
        <div style="height: 5px;"></div>
    <div ng-controller="ninjaController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search Ninjas">
    <ul class="liststyles" style="padding: 0px !important;">
        <li class="textstyles" ng-repeat ="ninja in ninjas | orderBy : order | filter: search">
            {{ ninja.name }} - {{ ninja.rate | currency }}
            <span class="cancel" ng-click="removeNinja()">x</span>
            <span class="belt" style="background-color: {{ ninja.belt }}">{{ ninja.belt }}</span>
        </li>
        <!-- <div class="line"></div> -->
    </ul>
</div>
</html>
```

The issue occured after i implemented the removeNinjas function. Here's my Js file with controller.

```
var newApp = angular.module('ninjaApp', []);

newApp.controller('ninjaController', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.removeNinja() = function(ninja){
        var removedNinja = $scope.ninjas.indexOf(ninja);
        $scope.ninjas.splice(removedNinja, 1);
    }

    $scope.ninjas = [
        {name : 'Kevin', belt : 'Red', rate: 100, available: true},
        {name : 'hitler', belt : 'Yellow', rate: 250, available: false},
        {name : 'goku', belt : 'Brown', rate: 450, available: true},
        {name : 'shenron', belt : 'Black', rate: 850, available: false}
    ]
}]);
```

the x should remove the selected ninja.
the console error -

> angular.min.js:127 TypeError: $scope.removeNinja is not a function
>
> ```
>     at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:5)
>     at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:45)
>     at S.instance (angular.min.js:97)
>     at p (angular.min.js:71)
>     at g (angular.min.js:64)
>     at g (angular.min.js:64)
>     at g (angular.min.js:64)
>     at g (angular.min.js:64)
>     at angular.min.js:64
>     at angular.min.js:22
> (anonymous) @ angular.min.js:127
> (anonymous) @ angular.min.js:99    
> $apply @ angular.min.js:155
> (anonymous) @ angular.min.js:22
> invoke @ angular.min.js:45
> c @ angular.min.js:22
> Uc @ angular.min.js:22
> Ae @ angular.min.js:21
> (anonymous) @ angular.min.js:348
> b @ angular.min.js:38
> ```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question it is not useful to other readers as it was resolved as a simple typo.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have **`()`** in your code, it should be just

```
$scope.removeNinja = function(ninja){
```